# Why splice syscall fails when my program runs on Linux but succeeds when it runs in gdb?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I try to run a book's sample code. Its function is to accept a line of input and output it to the standard output and operation parameters specified file.
Here is the code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf( "usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0] );
        return 1;
    }
    int filefd = open( argv[1], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0666 );
    assert( filefd > 0 );

    int pipefd_stdout[2];
        int ret = pipe( pipefd_stdout );
    assert( ret != -1 );

    int pipefd_file[2];
        ret = pipe( pipefd_file );
    assert( ret != -1 );

    //the first splice()
    ret = splice( STDIN_FILENO, NULL, pipefd_stdout[1], NULL, 32768, SPLICE_F_MORE | SPLICE_F_MOVE );
    assert( ret != -1 );

    ret = tee( pipefd_stdout[0], pipefd_file[1], 32768, SPLICE_F_NONBLOCK ); 
    assert( ret != -1 );

    //the second splice()       
    ret = splice( pipefd_file[0], NULL, filefd, NULL, 32768, SPLICE_F_MORE | SPLICE_F_MOVE );
    assert( ret != -1 );

    //the third splice()
    ret = splice( pipefd_stdout[0], NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, NULL, 32768, SPLICE_F_MORE | SPLICE_F_MOVE );
    printf("errno:%d\n",errno);
    assert( ret != -1 );


    close( filefd );
        close( pipefd_stdout[0] );
        close( pipefd_stdout[1] );
        close( pipefd_file[0] );
        close( pipefd_file[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

After i compiled the code, i ran it and typed "123", it can't output to stdout, the third splice() fails and errno is 22. here is the screenshot of result:
[p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gksU9.png)

And when i use gdb to run the code, it works normally. Here is the screeshot:
[p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13pXx.png)

kernel version: 4.19.163-1

gcc version: 10.2.0

gdb version: 10.1

my compile command: g++ test.cpp -g -o LinuxServer

my run command: ./LinuxServer test.txt

my gdb command: gdb LinuxServer

So why the splice syscall fails when my program runs on Linux but succeeds when it runs in gdb?

Comment: Instead of asserting the return value of system calls which *can* fail - which is **never a correct** way of using assert - check the return value and use `perrno()` to print out a message **and** a description of the value of `errno` after the failure. If a book indeed uses assert for this, then maybe you should try to reach the author...

Comment: @Antti Haapala  Thanks for your advice, but i didn't wrote this code, and my focus is on why running the program directly will make mistakes while running GDB will not.

Comment: Well, for what it is worth, I couldn't find any way to reproduce EINVAL on my 5.4.0-62-generic kernel...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In linux manual splice(2), there is a description of ERRORS: EINVAL The target file is opened in append mode.

The stdout in my terminal is at append mode, that's why the third splice syscall fail.

And to solve this problem, we can add `fcntl(STDOUT_FILENO, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDOUT_FILENO, F_GETFL) & ~O_APPEND);`before the splice syscall.